# limit of $\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right)^{n}$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, exponential-function

For $x>0$, the limit when $n\rightarrow \infty$ of
\begin{equation}
F_n(x)=\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right)^{n}=\left( 1-\frac{1}{1+nx} \right)^{n}
\end{equation}
is equal to $e^{-1/x}$. So
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( 1-\frac{1}{1+nx} \right)^{n}=e^{-1/x}
\end{equation}

I don't understand how to get from the left side of equality to the right side.
I am applying the following identity
$$e^{x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n} $$

I am trying to apply this identity

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle e^{-1/x}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( 1+\frac{-1/x}{n} \right)^{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n-1/x}{n} \right)^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( \displaystyle\frac{\frac{nx-1}{x}}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left( \frac{n^2x-n}{x} \right)^n
\end{equation}
But you can't get the mathematical expression indicated.

Comment: You are missing $\lim$ in several places. Btw $$
\left( {\frac{{nx}}{{1 + nx}}} \right)^n  = \left( {\frac{1}{{\frac{1}{{nx}} + 1}}} \right)^n  = \frac{1}{{\left( {1 + \frac{{1/x}}{n}} \right)^n}} \to \frac{1}{{e^{1/x} }} = e^{ - 1/x} .
$$

Comment: Ok. I´m goint to add the limits

Answer (score 4):

You can rewrite
$$\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right)^n=\left(1-\frac{1}{1+nx}\right)^n=\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{1+nx}\right)^{1+nx}\right]^{\frac{1}{x}}\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{1+nx}\right)^{-1}\right]^{\frac{1}{x}}\longrightarrow (e^{-1})^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot1=e^{-\frac{1}{x}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $L=\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)^{g(x)} \rightarrow 1^{\infty}$, then
$L=\exp[\lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)[f(x)-1]]$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right)^{n}=\exp[\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} [\frac{-n}{1+nx}]=\exp[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [\frac{-1}{1/n+x}]]=e^{-1/x}.$$